# How to save trajectories of tracked objects with trackpy?

Tags: python, trackpy

I am testing http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/stable/

You can access my image data here: http://goo.gl/fMv5oE

My code for tracking objects in subsequent video images is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'  # Set grayscale images as default.

import trackpy as tp
import pims

v = pims.ImageSequence('F:/*.png')

f = tp.batch(v[:100],diameter=21,threshold=25)

t = tp.link_df(f, 5)
```

How can I save `t`? (I am new to Python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you can serialize objects using [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(t,open("filename.pck","wb"))
```

Also looking at the [documentation o TrackPy](http://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/stable/tutorial/walkthrough.html?highlight=save#preview-of-advanced-features) you can find some ways to store data as a Panda matrix.

Comment: Is this a binary format? To be able to exchange the found trajectories with e.g. mathematica to save tracks as in asci format.

For example:

Particle name, frame number, x, y. Is this possible?

Comment: `Pickle` is a serialization for Python objects. It's not a fully binary but it's not easily readable either. Maybe `TrackPy` Panda matrix would be better to exchange data with Mathematica